# Confirm password validation not working in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Why is my password and confirm password validation not working? It works fine in JS Fiddle but not working my program

Here's the Js fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gUSZS/)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" >
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

            app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
                $scope.cityArray = ["hyderabad", "secunderabad", "delhi", "mumbai"];
                $scope.submit = function ($event) {
                    if ($scope.myForm.$invalid) {
                        // Or some other update
                        $scope.myForm.$submitted = true;
                        $event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });

            app.directive('nxEqualEx', function () {
                return {
                    require: 'ngModel',
                    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, model) {
                        if (!attrs.nxEqualEx) {
                            console.error('nxEqualEx expects a model as an argument!');
                            return;
                        }
                        scope.$watch(attrs.nxEqualEx, function (value) {
                            // Only compare values if the second ctrl has a value.
                            if (model.$viewValue !== undefined && model.$viewValue !== '') {
                                model.$setValidity('nxEqualEx', value === model.$viewValue);
                            }
                        });
                        model.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                            // Mute the nxEqual error if the second ctrl is empty.
                            if (value === undefined || value === '') {
                                model.$setValidity('nxEqualEx', true);
                                return value;
                            }
                            var isValid = value === scope.$eval(attrs.nxEqualEx);
                            model.$setValidity('nxEqualEx', isValid);
                            return isValid ? value : undefined;
                        });
                    }
                };
            });
        </script>

        <title>Registration Form</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-login">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <h2 class="text-muted">Registration form</h2>
                                <div>
                                    <form name="myForm" action="RegistrationServlet.do" method="POST" novalidate>

                                        Password:
                                        <input type="password" nx-equal-ex="pwd" class="form-control" name="pwd" ng-model="pwd" required placeholder="Password"/>
                                          <span style="color:red" ng-show="form.pwd.$error.nxEqualEx">Must be equal!</span>

                                        Confirm Password:<input type="password" nx-equal-ex="pwd2" class="form-control" ng-model="pwd2" name="pwd2" required placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
                                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="form.pwd2.$error.nxEqualEx">Must be equal!</span>

                                        <button class="form-control btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click="submit($event)">Submit</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS password confirmation noMatch not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842216/angularjs-password-confirmation-nomatch-not-working)

Comment: No its not. Yes I got the code from SO but applying the same directive in my project is not working. I checked all the typos and field names but its not working? What did I miss?

Comment: Any error in the console ?

Comment: Didn't find any errors in console

Comment: I just copy paste your code and it's working fine :)

Comment: @squiroid How come it isn't working for me. Could please create a plunker if its working for you?

Comment: Plunker :- http://plnkr.co/edit/K2cAKvUyNLOFlxqpCX8S?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81283/discussion-between-squiroid-and-kittu).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should be using this:

```
nx-equal-ex="pwd"
```

instead of

```
nx-equal-ex="pwd2"
```

Comment: Open the js file in console and put a breakpoint on this line: 
var isValid = value === scope.$eval(attrs.nxEqualEx);

Let me know what you see in valid and scope.$eval(attrs.nxEqualEx)